# Angular Elements Script Import vs Element Reference Location

Tags: angular, angular-elements

We're building out Angular **elements** for a project at work and came across something weird, but maybe it's not that weird...

The  [**Angular Elements**](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#d524) containing script import on the page must come after the element reference (which I guess makes sense, but when the order is reversed IE the element reference in the DOM comes before the script import, nothing happens.  No error message, no element binding no nothing.)

Is this expected behavior?  Should the element reference always come before the script import?

Comment: Is this referring to the new cutting edge ng6 elements? https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#d524 - If so, I suggest you clarify that since most people will be unfamiliar with them and you will get downvoted ... +1 to help you out ;)

Comment: yeap absolutely. Bleeding edge baby